# InDesign: Frame Edges only visible on some objects

Tags: adobe-indesign, vector

I have copied a logo from Illustrator and pasted it into InDesign, and noticed the blue **Frame Edges** are missing from some of the letter forms. All objects in InDesign are supposed to have a visible edge whose color corresponds with the layer color, correct?

I've seen this happen before, and was wondering if someone could explain what is happening here. Does it have something to do with the way the object was drawn in Illustrator?

[image: Logo with some edges visible and invisible]

Answer (score 1):

InDesign doesn't show the frame edge if the shape is open. Check each point of the S, U and O in Illustrator, this points are open:

[image: Open Points]

Join the open points and copy/paste again.

If the shapes are in a group or a compound shape and there is an open shape, the whole group will not have the blue frame.

[image: OpenPoints]